# Is it possible to save certain parts of a screenshot

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to reduce the time necessary to create screenshots. I want to skip reopening and cutting and saving. Instead I'd like to use a python script to determine the size of the part of the screen and crop the screenshot accordingly.

So, there's three (four) questions in one:

- Is it possible to take a screenshot with python?
- Can I edit the screenshot with python?
- Can I determine the size of an element in the user interface to crop accordingly?
- Is there already a solution out there?

Comment: I never new there was a screenshot functionality built into blender.. Learn some thing new every day :)
Anyway, I'm on linux with KDE so I always just used Ksnapshot which has an option to box select the region for capture. There might a program with similar functionality for windows.

Comment: I learned most of blender through working on problems of others. It has lots of gems hidden in plain sight. 
You can use "Alt+f3" for Screencasting. create a movie out of it in VSE and Add Audio and text as you see fit.
I also like to use Spacebar Menu a lot.

Answer (score 9):

*This answer is given with assumption that you would like to save different windows screen shot only.*

Here are the steps to take screenshots of specific windows in Blender e.g 3dView, UV Windows, Properties.

1. Hover your mouse over required window.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
3. Before saving screen shot, Uncheck ***Full Screen*** box to save only specific windows shot. It is available in ***Save Screenshot*** Properties Box.

Comment: Thank you, that's part of what I need. Although I'd sometimes like to dissect further

Answer (score 6):

To use the [screenshot feature](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Screenshots) see the [`bpy.ops.screen.screenshot`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.ops.screen.html?highlight=screenshot#bpy.ops.screen.screenshot) operator. To crop to the active window/editor use the `full` option:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(filepath="//output.png", full=False)
```

Comment: Now that one's cool. if I learn how to assign a shortcut to a script, the save screen won't bother me, since it's just dumping shots out.

Comment: @Haunt_House No python required to set this up, you can set the operator parameters in the shortcut. See [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Input) for more info.

Comment: Do I do anything wrong? I click the folder icon in the shortcut and I select a path and the textbutton stays blank.

Comment: @Haunt_House You seem to have found a bug. I typed the path directly and it works fine.